# AWS CLI works for user, command not found when run as root

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I installed AWS CLI and it's working fine, but when I run it with sudo I get this:

```
holland: ~ > aws --version
aws-cli/2.11.4 Python/3.11.2 Linux/5.14.0-130.el9.x86_64 exe/x86_64.centos.9 prompt/off
holland: ~ > sudo aws --version
sudo: aws: command not found
```

I'm hoping there's some obvious solution that someone can give me, but if not I'd appreciate some guidance on how to troubleshoot this.

I'm using CentOS

Comment: The `aws` application is not on your PATH when run via sudo. But ... why are you using sudo anyway? It's not required.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't consider different PATHs for different users, still learning. I'm using the command in a bash script that is run by root. I could have worked around it but I wanted to know why it wasn't working.

Comment: Suggestion: [Fixing the “Command Not Found” Error When Using Sudo](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/sudo-command-not-found), if you need it.